# SpringMVC submit form behavior

Tags: forms, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am newbie in SpringMVC and I need your help to undestand this POST request behavior.

here the form (model):

```
    public class ReferenteForm {

       private Integer id;
       private String descrizione;

       .. getter/setter

    }
```

here the controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("/referente")
    public class ReferenteController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String setupUpdate(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model uiModel) {

            logger.info("Setup ..");

            // get data
            Referente referente = referenteService.getById(id);

            // assign to form 
            ReferenteForm referenteForm = toReferenteForm(referente);

            //
            uiModel.addAttribute("referenteForm", referenteForm);

            return "referente/edit";
        }    


        @RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String update(@Valid ReferenteForm refForm,
                            BindingResult bindingResult, 
                            Model uiModel,
                            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, 
                            Locale locale) {

            logger.info("id.............."+refForm.getId());
            logger.info("descrizione....."+refForm.getDescrizione());

        }    

    }
```

here the view corresponding to "referente/edit":

```
        <form:form modelAttribute="referenteForm" method="post">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Descrizione:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="descrizione" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <button type="submit">
                <span>Save</span>
            </button> 
            <button type="reset">
                <span>Reset</span>
            </button>           

        </form:form>
```

I start triggering setupUpdate() method by GET request something like: 
/myapp/referente/update/30
The method get data from underlying service (not shown) build a simple ReferenteForm object, put it the model to be viewed by edit.jsp (referente/edit).
Then, I can see data of referente with id=30 showed by edit.jsp and ready to be edited.
I submit the form (POST request), so update() method will be triggered.
I am surprised to see ID, where it came from?
Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you see the id?

Comment: in the udate method, I expected null value because ID field is not present in the form.